# Flutter Fire Store - Assigning individual document fields to variables

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm attempting to show a user's profile image on their home page by pulling the user's **'imageUrl'** from their Fire Store document.  I already have the app setup to where the user can upload a new image which updates the 'imageUrl' in Fire Store, but I don't know how to have the 'imageUrl' as a variable so I can show it on the app screen.

I've been reading documentation online but It seems over simplified or out of date.  I've tried using **StreamBuilder**, but it pulls the data from every user in the database instead of for a single user.  I just need to know how to pull this one value and use it as a variable in my dart code using **"getString()"** with a document reference or the collection reference I already have, thank you.

[image]

```
class _UserPageState extends State<UserPage> {


User user = auth.currentUser!;
  final CollectionReference collectionReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users'); 

  // Get profileImageUrl from users userDoc
  String imageUrl = 'test'; // this should be the users imageUrl

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
            '${user.email}'), // this is being pulled from authentication not firestore
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
// --------------------------- I tried using a stream builder here ---------------------
                StreamBuilder(
                  stream: collectionReference.snapshots(),
                  builder: (BuildContext context,
                      AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return const Text(
                          'Something went wrong.'); // A: use incase the data does not load
                    }
                    final data = snapshot.requireData;
                    return ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: data.size,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Text(
                        // A: Stream builder will update with all of the users email addresses, I want this for one user exclusively
                            'My email is ${data.docs[index]['email']}'); 
                      },
```

Comment: Do you want to get this profile image once in this build method or do you need to listen to remote changes and update automatically when this changes in database?

Comment: I think it would be nice if it updated automatically but I don't think I need it.  I'm also not sure how costly that would be.  I don't think it's that important but if you know how to do that I would like to try it

Comment: If you need it only once, use a `FutureBuilder` instead of `StreamBuilder`, get the data for the user you need in the future and build the widget accordingly.

Comment: If you wan't to receive remote changes, then you can use `StreamBuilder` as you tried but query only one document instead of all as you do currently, like `collectionReference.doc(<document Id>).snapshots()` so that it will only return your user's document.

Comment: I'm getting an error for the collection reference when trying to switch from stream to future.  Error:  The argument type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>?'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
collection('users')
           .where("uid", isEqualTo: uid)
           .snapshots(),
```

To filter the data in firestore collection use "where". Store the user uid in offline and query it by where using the stored uid

Comment: So now my code reads:
stream: collectionReference.where("uid", isEqualTo: user.uid).snapshots(),

But how do I return this as a variable I can display outside of my stream builder?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following function to get single data from stream.

```
 Stream<UserModel> getSingleStreamData({String? uId}) {
return ref!.where(CommonKeys.id, isEqualTo: uId).snapshots().map((value) => value.docs.first.data());}
```

Comment: When I return this value, what will it be assigned to outside of the Stream?  
I want to use the variable outside of the stream, that's the part I need help assigning the value to

Comment: You can store it in the varibale and then you can use it whereever you want. or you can listen to the stream so thar wherever value gets updated it will listen to the stream and you will get new value. you can listen stream in init method. 

eg. getSingleStreamData(userid).listen(data){ }

Comment: Great!  Thank you so much